# What is the difference between spidev2.0 and spidev2.1?

Tags: debian, beagleboneblack

On my pocket beagle, which runs Debian, I have three spidev devices (spidev1.0, spidev2.0 and spidev2.1).

I have a SPI temp sensor on spi1 (which is spidev2.0 and spidev2.1). Loopback tests on 2.0 (by jumpering MOSI and MISO) worked. The data came back to me. However I was unable to send data to the temp sensor. When I switched to 2.1, everything worked normally.

Why is that? What is the difference between 2.0 and 2.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between 2.0 and 2.1 is the chip select pin (cs).

**spidev1.0**:
spi0_cs0 -> P1.06(default)

**spidev2.0**
spi1_cs0 -> P1.26(mode4), P1.32(mode1),P2.25(mode5),P2.30(mode3).

**spidev2.1**
spi1_cs1 -> P1.28(mode4), P1.30(mode1), P2.29(mode2), P2.31(mode4)

**Resource:**
https://github.com/beagleboard/pocketbeagle/wiki/System-Reference-Manual#Figure_1_PocketBeagle_Home_Page

Answer (score 0):

From what I've read, spidev2.0 and 2.1 refer to the Chip Select that has been configured for them. Which chipselect 2.0 is using though, I have no idea, but the chipselect for 2.1 must be the one labeled as chip select on the board.